# Delete multiple tables from a single query by separating from semicolon

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite, objective-c-blocks

I am trying to delete multiple tables in a single operation from sqlite. I tried separating it by semicolon but it didn't work out as expected. Here is my current code :

```
NSString *query = @"DELETE from Friends;DELETE from Stream;DELETE from Version";
```

I need some guidance on what could the problem be here, or if I am missing something.

Comment: do these table have some relationship?

Comment: no it does not have any relationship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make an atomic operation out of multiple statements, use a transaction:

```
BEGIN;
DELETE FROM Friends;
DELETE FROM Stream;
DELETE FROM Version;
COMMIT;
```

You have to execute these five commands one by one if you're using [sqlite3_prepare_v2](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html); with [sqlite3_exec](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html), you can execute them with one call (but `sqlite3_exec` would not support SQL parameters).

Comment: can't i use semi colon to separate it like i did ?